# Is the following map well defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am currently studying basic group theory. I am having trouble trying to prove that given a group $G$, and two subgroups $K$ and $H$ such that $H \leq K \leq G$ the following map is well defined:
$$\varphi:  G/K\times K/H \longrightarrow G/H$$
$$(gK,kH)\longmapsto gkH$$

As, one could take $g_1,g_2 \in G$ such that $g_2^-1g_1\in K-H$ so that $g_1K=g_2K$ but $g_1H \ne g_2H$. This means that (if $1$ is the group identity) although $(g_1K,1H)=(g_2K,1H)$, we have that  $\varphi(g_1K,1H) \ne \varphi(g_2K,1H)$ so the function is not well defined.

But, I don't know if this is a valid counterexample as thanks to a similar question ([finite index subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7002/finite-index-of-subgroup-of-subgroup)) a map similar to this one gives a bijection between the sets.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the order of $K$ and $H$

Comment: No, I mean that the function is independent from the class representative. That is to say that if two elements are equal on the domain then their images under the function are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your counterexample is valid.

Even simpler case. Take $H = \{ 1 \}$. You would get $G/K \to G$ defined by $g K \to g$, which certainly is not well defined.

Where do you see the similar map in the question that you link?

Comment: The similar map is in the second answer where they mention something related to the canonical map where they mention that the fiber is the image of the function I am defining.

Answer (score 0):

You're quite right that this map is not well-defined. There are well-defined homomorphisms $K/H \to G/H \to G/K$ forming what we call a [short exact sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence#Short_exact_sequence) of groups, but there is generally no splitting of such a sequence, that is, a homomorphism $G/K \to G/H$ that picks preimages. The point here is that you may still pick preimages for any coset in $G/K$, and that there are precisely $K/H$ available choices for each coset. This yields a set-theoretic bijection $G/H \cong K/H \times G/K $: an element in $G/H$ corresponds bijectively to its image under the projection $G/H \to G/K$ along with the choice of preimage encoded by $K/H$.

For example, consider the sequence of subgroups $4\mathbb{Z} \leq 2\mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{Z}$. The short exact sequence I mentioned above becomes $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. There is no splitting of this sequence by order considerations, but the preimage of, say, $0 \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is $\{0,2\} \subset\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, corresponds bijectively to $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, and similarly for the preimage of $1 \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is $\{1,3\} \subset\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is the $\varphi$ map above a preimage function from $G/K \rightarrow G/H$? Because what I ultimately want is a set theory bijection between those two sets.

Comment: @MiguelAngelAlarconBustos The map $gK \mapsto gH$ is generally not even a function.