# Let $A$ and $B$ be groups. Find the order of the central product $(A\times B)/Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

**The Problem**: Let $A$ and $B$ be groups. Assume $Z(A)$ contains a subgroup $Z_{1}$ and $Z(B)$ contains a subgroup $Z_{2}$. Suppose $Z_{1}$ is isomorphic to $Z_{2}$ by the map $x_{i} \mapsto y_{i}$ for all $x_{i} \in Z_{1}$. A *central product* of $A$ and $B$ is a quotient
$(A \times B) / Z$ where $Z = \{(x_{i}, y_{i}^{-1})\mid x_{i} \in Z_{1}\}$ and is denoted by $A*B$. Find $|A*B|$.

**My Question**: Clearly $|A*B|=|(A\times B)/Z|=|(A\times B)|/|Z|$ IF $A\times B$ is finite. But what if $|A\times B|=\infty$? We can't necessarily conclude that $|A*B|=\infty$ in this case.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’ll just point out that this seems like a particular case of studying the order of $G/N$, where $N$ is any normal subgroup. It doesn’t have to be infinite when $G$ has infinite order - however, I’m pretty sure that the equation $|G| = |N| [G:N]$ is still valid for arbitrary cardinals. In particular, in your case, $|A*B|$ finite implies $|Z|$ infinite.

Comment: If we let $[G:N]$ denote the cardinality of the set of (left) cosets of $N$ in $G$, then we have that for all $H\leq K\leq G$, $[G:H]=[G:K][K:H]$ (see [here for a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114189/742)). In particular, $|A\times B| = |(A\times B)/Z||Z|$  holds in the sense of cardinalities (more precise than simply saying "infinite"). So if $|A\times B|=2^{\aleph_0}$, and $|Z|=\aleph_0$, then $|(A\times B)/Z|=2^{\aleph_0}$, for example.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you so much for all the help Arturo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can say that $|A * B| = \infty$ if $A \times B$ is infinite.

If $Z_1$ is finite, then $A * B$ is factor of an infinite group by finite, thus infinite.

Otherwise, because elements of form $(a, e_B)$ belong to distinct cosets in $Z$ for different $a\in Z_1$, thus they already give us infinite number of elements in $Z_1 * Z_2$. And as $Z_1 * Z_2$ is subgroup of $A * B$, this implies that $A * B$ is also infinite.

Comment: One shouldn't use $0$ for the identity of a group unless you know you are using additive notation, and one usually does not use additive notation unless the group is abelian.

Comment: But $Z_1 \times Z_2$ is abelian.

Comment: But the ambient group is $B$, which isn't likely to be, so you shouldn't use $0$, because it's the identity of $B$ that you are talking about.

Comment: @mihaild "If $Z_1$ is finite, then $A∗B$ is factor of an infinite group by finite, thus infinite." I am afraid I have to disagree: $<n>$ is finite in $\mathbb{Z}$, but its index in $\mathbb{Z}$ is $n$, not $\infty$.

Comment: @DickGrayson: $\langle n\rangle$ is **infinite** in $\mathbb{Z}$, not finite. The only finite subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @mihaild I worked out "$Z_1$ is finite $\implies |A*B|=\infty$". But then I got confused by the notations: Is $Z_1*Z_2$ equal to $(Z_1\times Z_2)/Z$, where $Z$ is still as above, i.e., $Z= \{(x_{i}, y_{i}^{-1})\mid x_{i} \in Z_{1}\}$? And what is "classes"? I suppose you meant equivalent classes; but what is the equivalence relation here?