# Proving $|G:H| = |G:K| |K:H|$ when index $|G:K|$ or $|K:H|$ infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K \leq H \leq G$ for group $G$ of *possibly infinite* order. Several times, proofs for $|G:H| = |G:K| |K:H|$ have been posted on this site *whenever* $|G:H|< \infty$ (which also means that $|G:K|,|K:H|$ are finite). I'm interested in proving that this same result holds if one of $|G:K|, |K:H|$ is infinite.

Suppose $|G:K|$ is infinite. Then the number of left cosets of $K$ in $G$ is infinite. Then there are $\{g_\alpha: \alpha \in \Lambda \} \subseteq G$ so that $G = \displaystyle\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in \Lambda}^\infty g_\alpha K$. Clearly, $|G:K| |K:H|$ is also infinite. I want to show that this product equals $|G:H|$. Any suggestions on how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: The (pointwise) product of a transversal for $G/K$ and $K/H$ will be a transversal for $G/H$. Equivalently, bijections "distribute" over "internal disjoint" unions, so you can say $\bigsqcup gK=\bigsqcup g(\bigsqcup kH)=\bigsqcup (gk)H$.

Comment: Your assumptions appears to be that the left cosets are countably infinite, if the cosets are $g_iK$ for $i=1,2,\dots.$ Not all infinite sets are countable. You can probably prove that the cardinalities are the same for either or both infinite.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah, I forgot about uncountable. I have fixed the post.

Comment: Essentially, your theorem is due to $|X\times Y|=|X||Y|$ (which may be viewed as a definition of $|X||Y|$).

Comment: This answers your question: [Understanding the difference between two theorems related to $|G\,:\,K|=|H\,:\,K|\cdot|G\,:\,H|$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3114144/understanding-the-difference-between-two-theorems-related-to-g-k-h-k) (look at [Aturo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114189/386889))

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730728/104041) is a more direct duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Using the axiom of choice, we can find a right inverse, $\phi,$ of the quotient function $\pi_1:G\to G/K,$ and, likewise, a right inverse $\rho$ of the quotient function $\pi_2:K\to K/H.$

A fundamental property of these right inverses is that if $g_0,g_1$ are two elements in the range of $\phi$ such that $g_1^{-1}g_0\in K,$ then $g_0=g_1.$ And likewise for two elements in the image of $\rho.$

We will find a bijection between $G/K\times K/H$ and $G/H,$ and hence the two sets have the same cardinality whether these sets are finite or inf8nite.

Specifically, the bijection sends $p:(gK,kH)\mapsto \phi(gK)\rho(kH)H.$

We will first show that $p$ is one-to-one.

If $p(gK,kH)=p(g'K,k'H)$ then let $g_0=\phi(gK),$ $g_1=\phi(g'): k_0=\rho(kH), k_1=\rho(k'H).$

So $g_0k_0H=g_1k_1H.$ Then $g_1^{-1}g_0k_0H=k_1H\subseteq K,$ from which we get $g_1^{-1}g_0 k_0\in K,$ so $g_1^{-1}g_0\in K,$ and thus, since the $g_i$ are in the range of $\phi,$ $g_0=g_1$ and thus $gK=g_0K=g_1K=g'K.$

So we conclude that $k_0H=k_1H,$ and thus, as before $k_1^{-1}k_0\in H,$ and thus $k_0=k_1.$

Now, we will show $f$ is onto. Let $gH\in G/H.$ Let $g_0=\phi(gK).$ Then $g_0^{-1}g\in K$ and we can take $k_0=\rho(g_0^{-1}gK).$ Then we get $k_0H=g_0^{-1}gH$ or $g_0k_0H=gH,$ and thus $f(gK,\phi(gK)^{-1}gH)=gH.$

---

I do wonder if the axiom of choice is really required. It seems like we really do need $\phi$ and $\rho.$